# Is it possible to create a SUM of all of the unique names 2 dimensionally and their value like in the example below?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to find a function that will look through all of the sheet to find unique names and sum the value that was assigned at a specific date like below: (End result should be like the summary) - I am restricted to use this format and can't have all the names under one column and dates under another.
[image]

Comment: Sumifs(), but I would restructure the data.

Comment: I am proficient with excel and maybe this is why I can't think of a solution, there is no formula because I don't know any formula that can run on multiple columns, its is like a vlookup on the whole sheet and I don't know if anything like it exists.

Comment: @JvdV there is no formula to my knowledge or anything close to what I need that I have found, I am good with vlookups, match index even some experience with VBA, its general because there is nothing you can work around with to get this result to my knowledge and research.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simply old fashion Sumif function is enough.

In `I2`, formula copied down :

```
=SUMIF(A:E,H2,B:F)
```

[image]

Comment: Just shows that once in a mindset... Like this :)

Comment: OMG! Really elegant! I immediately started looking down every rabbit-hole without a clue that the problem has simple structure. Nice work.

Comment: Wow, can't believe it was that simple, I didn't know sumif would run vertically, thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

> *"I am trying to find a function that will look through all of the sheet to **find unique names** and **sum the value** that was assigned"*

Assuming:

- You indeed don't know the names beforehand (and over the course of 800+ columns and idemt dito rows (or more), it's "impossible" to write these out beforehand);
- You have an arbitrairy range (of up to 800 columns and many rows);
- Access to the BETA-channel of ms365.

[image]

Formula in `H3`:

```
=LET(X,WRAPROWS(TOCOL(A3:F5,1),2),Y,INDEX(X,0,1),Z,UNIQUE(Y),HSTACK(Z,BYROW(Z,LAMBDA(a,SUM((Y=a)*INDEX(X,0,2))))))
```

---

**Note:** The above is based on the assumption you **don't know** the unique names up front (as stated in the body of your question). Admittingly, if these are known, there are other/better answers.

Answer (score 2):

So laid the data out like so and used sumifs():

[image]

```
SUMIFS($C$2:$C$8,$B$2:$B$8,F2)
```

Will let you consider adding a date control: prior to,  equal to or after...

If you say you cannot change the source data, then make a data sheet to copy all the data, do the results like I show then link the results over...

So if you have to keep the format (instead of copying the data as already suggested - perhaps you missed that as you did not address that in your comment) then you could use sumifs() multiple times like so:

[image]

And just for fun playing with date control, still using your format:
[image]

Comment: Thanks but this is impossible, the sheet I gave as an example contains in reality dynamic information meaning that each day the amounts may change and have multiple users and values and this is spread over 800 columns of different days, I am restricted to this format and this is why I am asking this question here.

Comment: @FINISHUT so used your data layout, now you have two methods using this data format. IMHO it will only lead to more problems down the road - I made a suggestion about making a live copy and having a better layout...